# Cannot convert value of type () to expected argument type bool (Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following code:

```
func saveContext () {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    if managedObjectContext != nil {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !managedObjectContext.save(){
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

I got two errors: call can throw, but not marked with try and the error is not handled. The other one says cannot convert value of type () to expected argument type 'Bool'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is your deployment target?

Comment: Note that there are *many* Q&A's about `[swift] call can throw, but not marked with try` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `NSManagedObjectContext save()` is misleading. It doesn't actually have a return value in Swift. Instead, it can throw an error.

Your two errors are because you are ignoring the `throws` and treating it like it returns a `Bool`.

Your code needs to be something like:

```
func saveContext () {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    if managedObjectContext != nil {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print("Unable to save: \(error)")
                abort()
            }
        } else {
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506866-save misleading?

Comment: @MartinR In Swift, it documents a return value despite it having no return value.

Comment: Only the Objective-C view. The Swift view is documented as `func save() throws`

Comment: @MartinR Yes, the signature is correct in the Swift documentation but below that it documents the Return Value showing what true and false results mean.

Comment: Ahh – now see what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    do {
        try managedContext.save()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```

Comment: A word of commentary?

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon here. Please explain what was wrong and how your answer fixes the issue.

Comment: The question was how to fix this ;)

Comment: Yes but a good answer explains. The idea is to teach in addition to providing the solution.